# how to pass 2 results from jenkins script in 2 different variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a test.py file which prints out 2 variables - v1 and v2.

I have a jenkins file:

```
steps{
                script {
                    result= sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'python -u test.py')
                    println result
                }//script
            }
```

Is it possible to pass v1 and v2 from the script to two different variables in jenkins? Like:

```
steps{
                script {
                    sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'python -u test.py')
                    println v1
                    println v2
                    }//script
                }
```

Comment: can you please explain what the `v1` and `v2` variables you are referring to are?

Comment: In the first example, what it the output?

Comment: Hi, it is a seach function the test.py returns true or false if the search is done.
...
user_check = False
    for user_element in existing_users['Users']:
        if pnew_user_name in user_element['UserName']:
             user_check = True
            
    return user_check (v1)
now i also want to return the "user_element['UserName']" (v2)